# How can i pass the element between functions in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've got a few forms all on the same page, each one has the class .select_form and each one when you click a checkbox on the form sends the selected values via ajax.

What i want to be able to do is to reference the element selected (as there are multiple forms with the same css class) rather than naming each form differently. Ideally i guess i need to reference "this" and pass it around but i'm just not getting anywhere!

```
$('.select_form input').live("click", function(){
     check();
});


function check()
  {

     $("#ajax_totals").load("/stuff/things", $(".select_form").serializeArray());
  }
```

I guess i want something like:

```
$('.select_form input').live("click", function(){
     check(this);
});


function check(this)
  {

     $("#ajax_totals").load("/stuff/things", $(this).serializeArray());
  }
```

Comment: You guess? Have you tried it? Go ahead, try it!

Comment: `this` is a reserved word, so you can't use that in your function.

Comment: NOTE live is deprecated in jQuery after 1.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, you can just not use the variable `this` since it is [reserved](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words).

```
function check(elem)
{
     $("#ajax_totals").load("/stuff/things", $(elem).serializeArray());
}
```

Other option is using [call()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Thanks! @Joseph Silber got there first so i've got to give him the tick. But really appreciate your input and have upvoted yours!!

Comment: @John Looking at the timestamps: Mine "answered 22 mins ago", HIS "answered 21 mins ago" ...but who cares.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) to dynamically set what the value of `this` should be:

```
$('.select_form input').live("click", function(){
     check.call(this);
});

function check () {
    $("#ajax_totals").load("/stuff/things", $(this).serializeArray());
}
```